# Why do property values appear in scientific notation when parsing and writing results after executing queries on Galaxybase with Java?

Tags: java, graph-databases

Why do property values appear in scientific notation when parsing and writing the results returned to the client after executing algorithm queries in Java on Galaxybase?

Here is the code I wrote：

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        GalaxyBaseClient client = new GalaxyBaseClient("localhost", 8180);

        String query = "g.V().hasLabel('person').has('age', gt(20)).values('name', 'age')";
        GremlinResultSet result = client.submit(query);

        FileWriter fw = null;
        try {
            fw = new FileWriter("test.csv");

            String[] columnNames = {"name", "age"};
            for (int i = 0; i < columnNames.length; i++) {
                fw.write(columnNames[i]);
                if (i < columnNames.length - 1) {
                    fw.write(",");
                }
            }
            fw.write("\n");

            while (result.hasNext()) {
                Object[] values = result.next();
                for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
                    Object value = values[i];
                    fw.write(value.toString());
                    if (i < values.length - 1) {
                        fw.write(",");
                    }
                }
                fw.write("\n");
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (fw != null) {
                fw.close();
            }
            result.close();
            client.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How an object is written is totally depending on it's `toString` implementation in your code, so in your case on the implementation of whatever `Object` is returned from your `GremlinResultSet`. As we don't see any implementation of parsing here, I can't tell if it's from the parsing part or from the output part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Properties of type double, when written to a file after parsing, will become scientific notation.
The problem of this scientific notation is that java will automatically convert the data that is too big or too small to scientific notation.It can be solved by BigDecimal class of java.

```
String str=new BigDecimal(num+"").toString().
```

For your case, it can be optimized as follows:

```
            while (result.hasNext()) {
                Object[] values = result.next();
                for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
                    Object value = values[i];
                    if (value instanceof Double) {
                        String str = new BigDecimal(Double.toString((Double)value)).toString();
                        fw.write(str);
                    } else {
                        fw.write(value.toString());
                    }
                    if (i < values.length - 1) {
                        fw.write(",");
                    }
                }
                fw.write("\n");
            }
```